# my sql query get all rows under certain conditions of where clause

Tags: mysql

I have below my sql query,

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from `MYDATABASE`.`MYTABLE` 
   WHERE (Date(timestamp) BETWEEN '1970-01-01' and '2014-08-25') 
      and (COLA='') and (COLB = '') and COLC = '1' 
        AND (LIKE CLAUSE ON ANOTHER 10 COLUMNS) desc Limit  0, 10 ;
```

Now for ColA and COLB , I populate values sometimes and sometimes these come either as empty string or with Null value,so whenever I get these values,my query returns no rows.I can understand as why I get no rows,but now my requirement is to get all rows whenever I get null values or empty string for either of these columns.

How do I do this ? I tried with is not Null,but that breaks my code since it might work when I Pass null value to COLA and COLB but when COLA has valid value and COLB is passed null, it still gives all records when I want it to meet COLA condition ? Sorry I do not have any DBA , as I am wearing all hats for now.

Actual query looks something like below,

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from `MYDATABASE`.`MYTABLE` 
   WHERE (Date(timestamp) BETWEEN '1970-01-01' and '2014-08-25') 
      and (COLA='someparameter captured from UI,it could be null or empty string') and (COLB = 'someparameter captured from UI,it could be null or empty string') and COLC = '1' 
        AND (LIKE CLAUSE ON ANOTHER 10 COLUMNS) desc Limit  0, 10 ;


select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from MYTABLE WHERE (Date(timestamp) BETWEEN '1970-01-01' and 'CURRENTDATE') and COLA = ('12001'OR'12002') and COLB = ('VAL1'OR 'VAL2' OR 'VAL3' OR 'VAL4'OR 'VAL5'OR 'VAL6') and COLC = '1' and (COLD LIKE '%%' OR COLE LIKE '%%' OR COLF LIKE '%%' OR COLG LIKE '%%'  OR COLH LIKE '%%' OR COLI LIKE '%%' OR COLM LIKE '%%' OR COLN LIKE '%%' OR COLP LIKE '%%')  order  by Date(timestamp) desc Limit  0, 100
```

Comment: where do you get the values for the where clause from and how are you creating this statement (code ?)

Comment: Show your data, need more clear question..!!

Comment: I have a java class which captures the value from the UI. This query is part of DAO Class.

Comment: Mahida, please specify as what data you need, COLA and COLB are strings and mapped as varchar in database.

Comment: check my answer please. If so you should simplify your question according to the last sql only. The other two sql templates may not related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from `MYDATABASE`.`MYTABLE` 
WHERE (Date(timestamp) BETWEEN '1970-01-01' and '2014-08-25') 
and (COLA IS NULL OR COLA = '') and (COLB IS NULL OR COLB = '') and COLC = '1' 
AND (LIKE CLAUSE ON ANOTHER 10 COLUMNS) desc Limit  0, 10 ;
```

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Satish  even this query did not give me any results. So I ended up achieving the workaround via some other way. I added extra checks in my code

Comment: whenever colA comes out either as empty or null , I did some things like  COLA = (Value1 OR Value2 or Value3) and same thing for COL B.The only drawback of this approach was that I need to know all the possible values which can do into COLA and COLB.

Comment: @KiranBadi can you give input and sample output

Comment: Sathish, I just updated the post with query. COLA and COLB are formatted at my java code, which checks if value is null or empty, this value else pass actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Your should know `'12001'OR'12002'` is a logical expression, it returns a boolean value(`0-false/1-true` in Mysql).

```
select ('12001'OR'12002'), 1=('12001'OR'12002'), '1'=('12001'OR'12002'), '0'=('12001'OR'12002')

('12001'OR'12002') | 1=('12001'OR'12002') | '1'=('12001'OR'12002') | '0'=('12001'OR'12002')|
-------------------|----------------------|------------------------|-----------------------|
                  1|                     1|                       1|                      0|
```

So `COLA = ('12001'OR'12002')` will be false unless `COLA=1` or `COLA='1'`

You should change your java code, to generate the SQL statement with `in` instead of `=` and `,` instead of `OR`:

```
COLA in ('12001','12002')
```

Comment: Hi Jaugar, I know they are logical expression,but AHA I know what you intent to tell me. I will make changes to the code and will try to use IN.Hopefully it does not break my DAO.